# does autoload libraries codeigniter3 work?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have problem with codeigniter 3x and  I'm using php 8, in method login_aksi undefine property $input, $form_validation

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        
    }
    // menampilkan halaman login
    public function index(){
    $this->load->view('v_login');
    }
    // validasi login
    function login_aksi(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $sebagai = $this->input->post('sebagai');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
```

this my autoload

```
$autoload['packages'] = array();

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation');
```

I tried to change $aoutuload['libraries']

Answer (score 0):

are you add this code after  set rules ?

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
                        $this->load->view('myform');
}
else
$this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
```